# Can we write loops/conditions/block of code in a defer?

Tags: go, resultset, exit-code

Hi I am new to golang,

I use defer to close my result set like this.

```
defer res.Close()
```

I would like to check whether `res is nil` or not before calling  `res.Close()`.

I have below code block in the end of the function but it is not invoked when exited due to some error.

```
if(res!=nil){
            res.Close()
        }
```

I would like to know is there any way I could achieve this using `defer` .

```
defer  if(res!=nil){
                res.Close()
            }
```

Also what is the Idiomatic way for handling these situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass to `defer` a function call, and this can be a function literal :

```
defer func() {
     if res!=nil {
          res.Close()
     }
}()
```

Note that you usually avoid this problem by writing the `defer` statement right after the resource assignment.